# Can't see windows phone templates - Visual Studio 2012 Premium - Different languages

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I have installed the SDK for Windows Phone 8 however I can't create a Windows Phone project in Visual Studio 2012

I have an idea on why it's not working, my Visual Studio is in French and Windows Phone SDK is in English

Is there any quick fix without re-downloading either the sdk or vs 2012 in the same language?

Answer (score 0):

I finished downloading the [Visual Studio English Language Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=30681) and using VS2012 in English instead of copying around the templates from one language to another.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to install both Visual Studio 2012 and Windows Phone SDK in the same language. Otherwise the templates won't appear.